# How to fix zip function for lazy list (aka "stream")?

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

I want to make function zip, that will be zip two lazy lists into one. For example, lazy list shown like regular list for more readability, zip [1;3;5;7;9;11] [2;4;6;8], returns [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;11].

I make this function:

```
type 'a lazyList = LNil | LCons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazyList);;

let zip list1 list2 =
    let rec zipHelper listA listB count = match (list1, list2) with
        | (LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB)) -> 
            if (count mod 2 == 0)
            then LCons(xA, function() -> zipHelper (xfA()) (xfB()) (count + 1))
            else LCons(xB, function() -> zipHelper (xfA()) (xfB()) (count + 1))
        | (LCons(x, xf), LNil) -> LCons(x, function() -> zipHelper (xf()) LNil count)
        | (LNil, LCons(x, xf)) -> LCons(x, function() -> zipHelper (xf()) LNil count)
        | (LNil, LNil) -> LNil
    in zipHelper list1 list2 0
    ;;

let rec ltake = function
    | (0, _) -> []
    | (_, LNil) -> []
    | (n, LCons(x, xf)) -> x :: ltake(n - 1, xf())
    ;;

let a = (LCons(1, function() -> LCons(3, function() -> LCons(5, function() -> LCons(7, function() -> LCons(9, function() -> LCons(11, function() -> LNil)))))));;
let b = (LCons(2, function() -> LCons(4, function() -> LCons(6, function() -> LCons(8, function() -> LNil)))));;
ltake (12, zip a b);;
```

Function ltake helps in testing, it returns lazy list in regular list. Now my function zip returns me [1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in your `match` statement.

> ```
> let zip list1 list2 =
>     let rec zipHelper listA listB count = match (list1, list2) with
> ```

You don't want to match on `list1` and `list2`, but `listA` and `listB`.

You should also look into these calls,

> ```
> then LCons(xA, function() -> zipHelper (xfA()) (xfB()) (count + 1))
> else LCons(xB, function() -> zipHelper (xfA()) (xfB()) (count + 1))
> ```

Do you really want to pass as argument both tails?

Comment: Welcome! Also note this can be done without a counter. You can insert two elements, one from each list, if both lists are non-empty. Furthermore, in the case where one of them is empty you don't need any more recursive calls.

Comment: And that's how the pros do it: https://github.com/c-cube/oseq/blob/5e9e38744160e45e09b434cbf55248cd0584dcb4/src/OSeq.ml#L410 (not my solution, that's why i'm leaving it as a link)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right code, that works:

```
let zip list1 list2 =
    let rec zipHelper listA listB count = match (listA, listB) with
        | (LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB)) -> 
            if (count mod 2 == 0)
            then LCons(xA, function() -> zipHelper (xfA()) listB (count + 1))
            else LCons(xB, function() -> zipHelper listA (xfB()) (count + 1))
        | (LCons(x, xf), LNil) -> LCons(x, function() -> zipHelper (xf()) LNil count)
        | (LNil, LCons(x, xf)) -> LCons(x, function() -> zipHelper (xf()) LNil count)
        | (LNil, LNil) -> LNil
    in zipHelper list1 list2 0
    ;;
```

Changes:

After adding element to list, that I will be returning, I have to call zipHelper function with arguments tail of list, from which I take head and second list, not only it tail.

Just miss naming of lists in match, like said commentator previously.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Jorge Adriano's answer, I quickly built the version they proposed:

```
let lnil = LNil
let lcons a l = LCons (a,l)

let rec zip = function
  | LCons (xA, xfA) as fA ->
    ( function
      | LCons(xB, xfB) ->
        lcons xA (fun () -> lcons xB (fun () -> zip (xfA ()) (xfB ())))
      | LNil -> fA
    )
  | LNil ->
    ( function
      | LCons (xB, xfB) as fB -> fB
      | LNil -> LNil
    )
```

I also separated `ltake` into the take and the list conversion (not tailrecursive implemented) and added a repeat to test corecursive datastructures:

```
let rec ltake n = function
    | LNil -> LNil
    | LCons(x, xf) ->
      if n == 0
      then LNil
      else lcons x (fun () -> ltake (n - 1) (xf ()))

let rec of_list = function
  | [] -> LNil
  | x :: xs -> LCons (x, fun () -> of_list xs)

let rec to_list = function
    | LNil -> []
    | LCons (x,xs) -> x :: (to_list (get xs))

let repeat n =
  let rec aux n () = LCons (n, aux n) in
  aux n ()
```

we can test it on the original input:

```
utop # ltake 12 (zip a b) |> to_list ;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 11]
```

and with a repeat:

```
utop # ltake 12 (zip (repeat 1 ) (repeat 2)) |> to_list ;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 1; 2; 1; 2; 1; 2; 1; 2; 1; 2]
```